# Update Trigger conditional values

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have been searching around stackoverflow but I have not found what I'm looking for.
I have a Sql Server Database. One table with a field "Priority" I would like to update on every insert or update.

The problem is that I want to perform a Priority pile using this rules:
1.-If the value I try to insert has a prority value that already exists then every consecutive row in the table must change its priority value adding 1. 
2.-If the value I try to insert has a priority that not exists then the trigger does nothing.

This is the trigger I haver built:

```
ALTER trigger [Priority]
on [dbo].[TBL_PILA]
after insert, update    
 AS
    declare @priority int;
    declare @reg_id int;
    SELECT @reg_id =i.id from inserted i;   
    SELECT @priority =PRIORITY from TBL_PILA where ID =@reg_id    
      -- perform update here in TBL_PILA table        
    UPDATE TBL_PILA SET PRIORITY=PRIORITY+1 WHERE ID <>@reg_id AND PRIORITY>=@priority
 GO
```

Edit: As Suggestions, I change the trigger body like this:

```
ALTER trigger [Priority]
on [dbo].[TBL_PILA]
after insert, update  
if exists (select * 
         from inserted i join TBL_PILA m
         on i.ID = m.ID
         )
update TBL_PILA set PRIORITY = PRIORITY + 1 
where exists (select * from inserted i 
              join TBL_PILA m
              on i.ID = m.ID
              where m.PRIORITY>=i.PRIORITY)
```

Now I have a new problem: the priority value inserted is affected by the trigger and it is added 1 too.

Does anybody knows how to increase priority values only affecting some range as I explained below?

The problem is whenever exists a few consecutive values and one not consecutive value the trigger must stops.
Example
Priority 1 2 4 5 6 8

If I try to insert a row with priority=3 the result should be:
1 2 3 4 5 6 8

Then If I try to insert a row with priority=4 then the result should be:
1 2 3 4 (inserted value) 5 (4+1) 6 (5+1) 7 (6+1) 8

But using the trigger I built I get this: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 9 (8+1)

Comment: Your trigger is broken. `inserted` can contain *multiple* rows, so assigning a value to a scalar variable (e.g. `SELECT @reg_id =i.id from inserted i;`) is inherently broken.

Comment: As Damien says, treat `inserted` like a table with the same structure as the one your trigger is working on. Join to it or use the values in an IN or EXISTS clause.